# How to create database in Mongodb using Node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Iam beginner, first i installed npm install mongodb, then i create js file as demo_create_mongo_db.js

I used following code to create database

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
//Create a database named "mydb":
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
 if (err) throw err;
 console.log("Database created!");
 db.close();
 });
```

then i just run node demo_create_mongo_db.js following error occured

[image: this error found]

Why this error occur? how can i handle this?

Thanks

Comment: You need to install MongoDB database in your system and run mongod server to listen to any mongodb request on port 27017.  In a separate terminal  run mongod.exe also

Comment: Your question is how to create db or connect to DB?

Answer (score 1):

> index.js

At first, install MongoDB module by running this command.

> npm install mongodb --save

Just keep in mind that you can not create the only database. You have to create also the collection to see your new database.

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new mongodb.MongoClient(uri);

client.connect((err) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log('connection created');
    }
    const newDB = client.db("YourNewDatabase");
    newDB.createCollection("YourCreatedCollectionName"); // This line i s important. Unless you create collection you can not see your database in mongodb .

})
```

Now run this index file by the following command in your terminal

> node index.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mongoose library to connect to MongoDB in Node JS

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/'+db_to_connect,{ useNewUrlParser: true });

 var db = mongoose.connection;
 db.on('error', function(){             
 });
 db.once('open', ()=> {
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem your mongo server havn't runing yet!!
run `mongo` in comment line to check if mongo server is runing or not.